# I can't run JUnit in Eclipse for git project

Tags: eclipse, github, junit

I am trying to work in GitHub project and I need to understand the code 
so when I go to Run as I have just Run configuration 
* I installed JUnit plugin for eclipse 
that is the my screen:

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try right-clicking on the file name in the Package Explorer itself?

Comment: yes I tried to click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import hipster-examples as a separate project, so that eclipse recognize the src folder as a source folder.

try to create a new empty workspace and follow this steps:

1. righ click on package explorer
2. Import...
3. Existing maven projects: 
   [image]
4. set as root directory the root path of your local git
   repository - using your example as a reference, what I mean is the root path of "hipster" project and select all the projects:
   [image]

Now everything should work fine:
[image]
[image]

As you can see in these screenshots, as a result, there is NOT one single project containing everything, but there are all the projects, each of them declared as a "root element" of the workspace.

Comment: It is not work is still recognize it as git project...... if I remove git eclipse plugin is it work?!

Comment: the problem is not that it is recognized as a git project: each project can have multiple natures.
The problem is that "hipster" itself is not a java project, is just the root of the repository. You should import separately each contained projects: hipster-core, hipster-all, hipster-example, etc... I found the same github repository you are using and I tried to do as I said, and it works! I'm going to edit my answer to give you a better explanation of what you should do!

Comment: I implemented  your solution but when I imported as existing maven projects ... I got message that show is eclipse can't read pom.xml

Comment: please, provide the error message or a screenshot, maybe I can help you!